# DateTime search problems ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a database that stores lottery form submissions from users. One of the columns is a DateTime column that is populated with the current DateTime every time someone submits a form. I want to be able to search by the DateTime column so I can pull up all the forms entered on a particular day.

I'm not getting any errors when I perform the search, just my custom message that "No results matching that search criteria". I've tried disabling the jquery datepicker and tried copying and pasting the exact DateTime field from the DB into the search box and still nothing. Obviously I'm missing something but I can't figure out what. Any help is much appreciated.

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class adminDefault : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

}

protected void lastNameButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand comm;
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["10thLottoApp"].ConnectionString;
    conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT First, Last, Addr1, C, S, Z, dayphone, eveningphone, email, tripCC, tripCCexpiration, tripCVV, tripCCname, memberCC, memberCCexpiration, memberCVV, memberCCname, membership, hutCredit, creditName, GroupName, Id, LotteryChoices, dateTime FROM Lotto WHERE Last LIKE '%'+ @Name + '%'", conn);
    comm.Parameters.Add("@Name", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = nameSearch.Text;

        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
        if (!reader.HasRows)
            {
                noMatchLabel.Text = "No results matching that search criteria.";
            }
        else
        {
            grid.DataSource = reader;
            grid.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "Id" };
            grid.DataBind();
            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();
            noMatchLabel.Text = null;
        }

}


protected void groupNameButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand comm;
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["10thLottoApp"].ConnectionString;
    conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT First, Last, Addr1, C, S, Z, dayphone, eveningphone, email, tripCC, tripCCexpiration, tripCVV, tripCCname, memberCC, memberCCexpiration, memberCVV, memberCCname, membership, hutCredit, creditName, GroupName, Id, LotteryChoices, dateTime FROM Lotto WHERE GroupName LIKE '%'+ @GroupName + '%'", conn);
    comm.Parameters.Add("@GroupName", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = groupSearch.Text;

    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
    if (!reader.HasRows)
    {
        noMatchLabel.Text = "No results matching that search criteria.";
    }
    else
    {
        grid.DataSource = reader;
        grid.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "Id" };
        grid.DataBind();
        reader.Close();
        conn.Close();
        noMatchLabel.Text = null;
    }
}

protected void dateSearch(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand comm;
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["10thLottoApp"].ConnectionString;
    conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT First, Last, Addr1, C, S, Z, dayphone, eveningphone, email, tripCC, tripCCexpiration, tripCVV, tripCCname, memberCC, memberCCexpiration, memberCVV, memberCCname, membership, hutCredit, creditName, GroupName, Id, LotteryChoices, dateTime FROM Lotto WHERE dateTime = @dateTime ", conn);

    comm.Parameters.Add("@dateTime", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(datesearch.Text);

    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
    if (!reader.HasRows)
    {
        noMatchLabel.Text = "No results matching that search criteria.";
    }
    else
    {
        grid.DataSource = reader;
        grid.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "Id" };
        grid.DataBind();
        reader.Close();
        conn.Close();
        noMatchLabel.Text = null;
    }

}

protected void grid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindLottoDetails();
}

private void BindLottoDetails()
{
    int selectedRowIndex = grid.SelectedIndex;
    int lottoId = (int)grid.DataKeys[selectedRowIndex].Value;
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand comm;
    SqlDataReader reader;
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["10thLottoApp"].ConnectionString;
    conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id, First, Last, Addr1, C, S, Z, dayphone, eveningphone, email, tripCC, tripCCexpiration, tripCVV, tripCCname, memberCC, memberCCexpiration, memberCVV, memberCCname, membership, hutCredit, creditName, GroupName, LotteryChoices, dateTime FROM Lotto WHERE Id=@Id", conn);
    comm.Parameters.Add("Id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
    comm.Parameters["Id"].Value = lottoId;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
        lottoFormDetails.DataSource = null;

        lottoFormDetails.DataSource = reader;
        lottoFormDetails.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "Id" };
        lottoFormDetails.DataBind();
        reader.Close();
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
protected void lottoFormDetails_ModeChanging(object sender, DetailsViewModeEventArgs e)
{
    lottoFormDetails.ChangeMode(e.NewMode);
    BindLottoDetails();
}
protected void lottoFormDetails_ItemUpdating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    int LottoId = (int)lottoFormDetails.DataKey.Value;
    TextBox newFirstTextBox = (TextBox)lottoFormDetails.FindControl("editFirstTextBox");
    TextBox newLastTextBox = (TextBox)lottoFormDetails.FindControl("editLastTextBox");
    TextBox newAddr1TextBox = (TextBox)lottoFormDetails.FindControl("editAddr1TextBox");
    TextBox newCityTextBox = (TextBox)lottoFormDetails.FindControl("editCityTextBox");
    TextBox newStateTextBox = (TextBox)lottoFormDetails.FindControl("editStateTextBox");
    TextBox newZipTextBox = (TextBox)lottoFormDetails.FindControl("editZipTextBox");
    TextBox newdaytimephoneTextBox = (TextBox)lottoFormDetails.FindControl("editdaytimephoneTextBox");
    TextBox neweveningphoneTextBox = (TextBox)lottoFormDetails.FindControl("editeveningphoneTextBox");
    TextBox newemailTextBox = (TextBox)lottoFormDetails.FindControl("editemailTextBox");
    TextBox newmembershipTextBox = (TextBox)lottoFormDetails.FindControl("editmembershipTextBox");
    TextBox newhutCreditTextBox = (TextBox)lottoFormDetails.FindControl("edithutCreditTextBox");
    TextBox newcreditNameTextBox = (TextBox)lottoFormDetails.FindControl("editcreditNameTextBox");
    TextBox newGroupNameBox = (TextBox)lottoFormDetails.FindControl("editGroupNameTextBox");
    TextBox newLotteryChoicesTextBox = (TextBox)lottoFormDetails.FindControl("editLotteryChoicesTextBox");
    string newFirst = newFirstTextBox.Text;
    string newLast = newLastTextBox.Text;
    string newAddr1 = newAddr1TextBox.Text;
    string newCity = newCityTextBox.Text;
    string newState = newStateTextBox.Text;
    string newZip = newZipTextBox.Text;
    string newdaytimephone = newdaytimephoneTextBox.Text;
    string neweveningphone = neweveningphoneTextBox.Text;
    string newemail = newemailTextBox.Text;
    string newmembership = newmembershipTextBox.Text;
    string newhutCredit = newhutCreditTextBox.Text;
    string newcreditName = newcreditNameTextBox.Text;
    string newGroupName = newGroupNameBox.Text;
    string newLotteryChoices = newLotteryChoicesTextBox.Text;
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand comm;
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["10thLottoApp"].ConnectionString;
    conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    comm = new SqlCommand("UpdateLotteryForm", conn);
    comm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    comm.Parameters.Add("Id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
    comm.Parameters["Id"].Value = LottoId;
    comm.Parameters.Add("NewFirst", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
    comm.Parameters["NewFirst"].Value = newFirst;
    comm.Parameters.Add("NewLast", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
    comm.Parameters["NewLast"].Value = newLast;
    comm.Parameters.Add("NewAddr1", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
    comm.Parameters["NewAddr1"].Value = newAddr1;
    comm.Parameters.Add("NewC", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
    comm.Parameters["NewC"].Value = newCity;
    comm.Parameters.Add("NewS", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
    comm.Parameters["NewS"].Value = newState;
    comm.Parameters.Add("NewZ", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
    comm.Parameters["NewZ"].Value = newZip;
    comm.Parameters.Add("Newdayphone", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
    comm.Parameters["Newdayphone"].Value = newdaytimephone;
    comm.Parameters.Add("Neweveningphone", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
    comm.Parameters["Neweveningphone"].Value = neweveningphone;
    comm.Parameters.Add("Newemail", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
    comm.Parameters["Newemail"].Value = newemail;
    comm.Parameters.Add("Newmembership", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
    comm.Parameters["Newmembership"].Value = newmembership;
    comm.Parameters.Add("NewhutCredit", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
    comm.Parameters["NewhutCredit"].Value = newhutCredit;
    comm.Parameters.Add("NewcreditName", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
    comm.Parameters["NewcreditName"].Value = newcreditName;
    comm.Parameters.Add("NewGroupName", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
    comm.Parameters["NewGroupName"].Value = newGroupName;
    comm.Parameters.Add("NewLotteryChoices", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1);
    comm.Parameters["NewLotteryChoices"].Value = newLotteryChoices;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    lottoFormDetails.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.ReadOnly);
    BindLottoDetails();
}


}
```

.aspx code

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/admin.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="adminDefault.aspx.cs" Theme="Blue" Inherits="adminDefault" %>
<%@ Import Namespace = "System.Data.SqlClient" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
      <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#<%=datesearch.ClientID%>").datepicker();
        });
  </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <div id="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2>10th Mountain Lottery App</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 sidenav">
            <ul>
                <li>Search Forms</li>
                <li>Display Full Lottery List</li>
                <li>Error Filtering</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <p>You can use the menu below to search for individual forms</p>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                        <h4>Lottery Form Search</h4>
                        <asp:Label runat="server">Search by Last Name: <asp:TextBox id="nameSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:Label>
                        <p><asp:Button id="nameSearchButton" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="lastNameButton" /></p>

                        <asp:Label runat="server">Search by Group Name: <asp:TextBox id="groupSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:Label>
                        <p><asp:Button id="groupsearchButton" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="groupNameButton" /></p>
                        <asp:Label runat="server">Search by Date: <asp:TextBox id="datesearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:Label>
                        <p><asp:Button id="dateSearchButton" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="dateSearch" /></p>
                        <asp:Label ID="noMatchLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:GridView id="grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="grid_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="First" HeaderText="First Name" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Last" HeaderText="Last Name" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="C" HeaderText="City" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="GroupName" HeaderText="Group Name" />
                                <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Select" Text="Select" />
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                        <br />
                        <asp:DetailsView ID="lottoFormDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" OnItemUpdating="lottoFormDetails_ItemUpdating" OnModeChanging="lottoFormDetails_ModeChanging">
                            <Fields>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="editFirstTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("First") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="insertFirstTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("First") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="FirstLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("First") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name">
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="editLastTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Last") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="insertLastTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Last") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="LastLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Last") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address">
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="editAddr1TextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Addr1") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="insertAddr1TextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Addr1") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Addr1Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Addr1") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City">
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="editCityTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("C") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="insertCityTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("C") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="CityLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("C") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="State">
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="editStateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("S") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="insertStateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("S") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="StateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("S") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Zip">
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="editZipTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Z") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="insertZipTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Z") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="ZipLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Z") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Daytime Phone #">
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="editdaytimephoneTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("dayphone") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="insertdaytimephoneTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("dayphone") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="daytimephoneLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("dayphone") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Evening Phone #">
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="editeveningphoneTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("eveningphone") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="inserteveningphoneTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("eveningphone") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="eveningphoneLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("eveningphone") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="editemailTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("email") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="insertemailTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("email") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="emailLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("email") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Membership">
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="editmembershipTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("membership") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="insertmembershipTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("membership") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="membershipLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("membership") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hut Credit">
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="edithutCreditTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("hutCredit") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="inserthutCreditTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("hutCredit") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="hutCreditLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("hutCredit") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hut Credit Name">
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="editcreditNameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("creditName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="insertcreditNameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("creditName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="creditNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("creditName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Group Name">
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="editGroupNameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GroupName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="insertGroupNameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GroupName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="GroupNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GroupName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Lottery Choices">
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="editLotteryChoicesTextBox" TextMode="multiline" Columns="75" Rows="10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LotteryChoices") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="insertLotteryChoicesTextBox" TextMode="multiline" Columns="75" Rows="10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LotteryChoices") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="LotteryChoicesLabel" TextMode="multiline" Columns="75" Rows="10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LotteryChoices") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                            </Fields>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <%#Eval("First")%> <%#Eval("Last") %> <%#Eval("dateTime") %>
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                        </asp:DetailsView>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content
```

>

Comment: I think you will have to create a minimal sample that could be looked into for replicating the issue.

Comment: It is *likely* that your column has a time component that you are not factoring -- you can't equate a datepicker date (which probably parses as `YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00`) to a `DATETIME` column that includes a time (`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS`).  You will probably need to change your search SQL to `WHERE dateTime >= @date1 AND dateTime < @date2` and pass `@date1` as `DateTime.Parse(datesearch.Text).Date` and `@date2` as `DateTime.Parse(datesearch.Text).Date.AddDays(1)` to both chop off the time portion and range-search across the selected day.

Comment: Thanks jimbobmcgee, that did the trick. Although I'm sure C Sigmon's answer would have worked too. I just tried yours first.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, you state that you are storing the data as a DateTime. This means you are getting the date and the time. Of course the time includes hours, minutes, seconds, etc...

In you query you need to CAST your DateTime to a Date in order to remove the time from it.

See this MSDN article for more clarification https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx